# What's the correct abstraction for storing a set of postgres enum values for reuse?

Tags: postgresql, enums

I have the following enum and table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE public.event_type as ENUM (
  'eat_apple',
  'eat_banana',
  'brush_teeth'
);

CREATE TABLE public.events (
  id integer not null,
  type public.event_type,
  created_at timestamp without time zone
);
```

I have a lot of queries that I'm writing against this table that are only concerned with a subset of the event types (`eat_apple` and `eat_banana`).

I could write each of these queries with a `WHERE type IN ('eat_banana', 'eat_apple')` clause, however there's a high likelihood that in future, I'll need to add an `eat_pear` event type.

What are the available abstractions in Postgres for storing a subset of these enum values for reuse throughout queries, in a way where the subset can be extended in future, such that existing queries take this into account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would ditch the enum completely and make event_type a proper table that contains a flag if it's a "default" type.

```
create table event_type
(
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null unique,
  is_default_type boolean not null default true
);

create table events 
(
  id integer not null,
  type integer not null references event_type,
  created_at timestamp without time zone
);
```

To find those with the default subset you can do:

```
select e.*
from events e
  join event_type et on et.id = e.type and et.is_default_type;
```

To maintain the default subset, you just change the flag. For convenience you can create a view from the above query, so you never need to worry about the join.

If you create the view using an `IN` operator instead of the join it's also automatically updateable.

Comment: You could use the enum as the primary key on the small table,  that's what I do, it's fairly painless.

Comment: Do you think this is preferable to a function that returned the subset of `type` values? It feels more visible/discoverable, but maybe less ergonomic. Alternatively, maybe just a view would suffice without the `event_type` table abstraction!

Answer (score 2):

You would use an array of type `event_type[]` and modify the query to the (equivalent)

```
WHERE type = ANY (array_value)
```

If you want to use a string constant, you could write

```
WHERE type = ANY ('{eat_banana,eat_apple}'::event_type[])
```